# tracking users in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

We are currently building an application which will have users login and be tracked as they surf the site.  I've looked into ASP.Net Membership but rather than use a username/password which the user or admin will have to setup, we've been asked to validate users against LDAP.  Currently we are using Sessions, so once a user is validated in LDAP we allow them into the site and save information into a Session variable, which is then checked in the Master page to make sure it exists on all pages, if not the user is bounced to login.

Is this a common approach, ok to do?  Or is there a way using Forms Authentication and Membership to validate against LDAP rather than the SQL tables.  So we can only use Membership for Roles, and not for creating users/passwords.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a pretty reasonable solution to me.

Otherwise search for .NET LDAP Membership Provider and see if any of the results look interesting.